# Segmentation fault when calling a function in c

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

The code is to print given numbers in a spiral fashion, like,

> 1 2 3
>   8 9 4
>   7 6 5

I am getting a segfault while calling the function `godown()`.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int o[100][100],c[100][100],p=0,q=0,m=0,n=0,a,i,j,r,d,l,u;
void goright(int r);
void goleft(int l);
void goup(int u);
void godown(int d);

int main()
{
    int r;
    printf("\nenter the no. of rows\n");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("\nenter the elements u want to print in a spiral fashion\n");
    for(i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<a;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&o[i][j]);
            getchar();
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<a;j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",o[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    r=a;
    goright(r);
    for(i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<a;j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",c[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

void goright(int r)
{
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        c[m][n]=o[p][q];
        q++;
        n++;
    }
    if(q>a)
    {
        q=0;
        p++;
    }
    else
    {
        q--;
        p++;
    }
    n--;
    m++;
    d=r-1;
    godown(d);
}

void godown(int d)
{
    for(i=0;i<d;i++)
    {
        c[m][n]=o[p][q];
        q++;
        m++;
    }
    if(q>a)
    {
        q=0;
        p++;
    }
    else
    {
        q--;
        p++;
    }
    m--;
    n--;
    l=d;
    goleft(l);
}

void goleft(int l)
{
    for(i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        c[m][n]=o[p][q];
        q++;
        n--;
    }
    if(q>a)
    {
        q=0;
        p++;
    }
    else
    {
        q--;
        p++;
    }
    n++;
    m--;
    u=l-1;
    goup(u);
}

void goup(int u)
{
    for(i=0;i<u;i++)
    {
        c[m][n]=o[p][q];
        q++;
        m--;
    }
    if(q>a)
    {
        q=0;
        p++;
    }
    else
    {
        q--;
        p++;
    }
    m++;
    n++;
    r=u;
    goright(r);
}
```

I don't understand why I am getting the segfault. While debugging, it seems the `goright()` function works properly, as I tried printing the elements of the spiral fashioned array 'c'. I have tried changing the names of variables and all, but nothing seems to help.

Comment: You are probably running out of bounds. Use a real debugger to step and inspect.

Comment: At some point, you must stop your recursion. You go on recursing unconditionally, eventually overflowing the stack.

Comment: Changing variable names does not usually change the behaviour...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your recursive code looks like this, more or less:

```
void goright(int r)
{
    ...
    godown(d);
}

void godown(int d)
{
    ...
    goleft(l);
}

void goleft(int l)
{
    ...
    goup(u);
}

void goup(int u)
{
    ...
    goright(r);
}
```

The stuff that I omitted (`...`)  does not contain any `return`statements, so this set-up will recurse forever, once underway. You can verify this by printing the argument of the `goxxx` functions in the first line: They will become negative with growing magnitude.

So you need a termination criterion for your rcursion. Your `go` functions could look like this:

```
void goright(int r)
{
    if (r > 0) {
        ...
        godown(d);
    }
}
```

or like this:

```
void goright(int r)
{
    if (r == 0) return;

    ...
    godown(d);
}
```

You still have problems with your code, mainly because you store the values to insert in a two-dimensional array. It yold be way easier to store these in a linear array of size `a*a` - you'd just have to keep track of one index that moves in a predictable manner.

And, please, don't define all your variables as globals. Many of them aren't needes, espacially the namesakes of the `goxxx` function arguments. And iterators like `i` and `j` should be local.

You can still use your recursive approach. Here's an example. It just fills the spiral with numbers counting upwards from 1. Note how te print loops don't go the full way, they stop short by one, so that a square will be printed like this:

```
r r r d
u     d
u     d
l l l d
```

That means you don't have to adjust your variables `m` and `n` after going too far. This adjustment is needed only when you go full circle, i.e. after you start going right again. This case also has an extra check to print the last central value for odd edge lengths.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int c[100][100], p=0, m=0, n=0;

void goright(int r);
void goleft(int l);
void goup(int u);
void godown(int d);

int main()
{
    int a;

    printf("\nenter the no. of rows\n");
    scanf("%d",&a);

    goright(a);

    for(int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < a; j++) {
            printf("%3d",c[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

void goright(int x)
{
    if (x == 1) c[m][n] = ++p;
    if (x <= 1) return;

    for(int i = 1; i < x; i++) {
        c[m][n++] = ++p;
    }

    godown(x);
}

void godown(int x)
{
    for(int i = 1; i < x; i++) {
        c[m++][n] = ++p;
    }

    goleft(x);
}

void goleft(int x)
{
    for(int i = 1; i < x; i++) {
        c[m][n--] = ++p;
    }

    goup(x);
}

void goup(int x)
{
    for(int i = 1; i < x; i++) {
        c[m--][n] = ++p;
    }

    m++;
    n++;

    goright(x - 2);
}
```